# Printing elements of char array from PROGMEM

Tags: serial, programming, progmem

Given:

```
const char* PROGMEM names[] = {"Foo","Bar"};
Serial.print(names[0]);
```

I get garbage output. Is there some function that will print the string from PROGMEM? E.G.:

```
Serial.print(<function name>(names[0]);
```

Comment: That's not how you use [PROGMEM](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/utilities/progmem/). You need to use the functions `pgm_read_***_near`

Comment: your strings are not in progmem. only the array of pointers to strings is there https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/utilities/progmem/

Answer (score 2):

Among many others, check out pgmspace.h utilities at
[AVR-libc](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/modules.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
const char PROGMEM b0 = pgm_read_dword(&(names[0]));
Serial.print(b0);
```

Comment: `PROGMEM` does nothing here